# splitting a pandas column by delimiter, two different sizes in the rows

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm attempting to split up a column in a pandas dataframe into multiple by a space delimiter. I realized that some of the rows have a date field and therefore it would need extra columns compared to the ones without it.
Heres an example of column values,

```
DA Firstname Lastname 09/30/2020 07:44 AM 9/23/2020 6:06:38 PM
JW Firstname Lastname 10/25/2020 11:06 AM None
```

The first row wouldn't fit a space delimiter because there are 8 spaces. The second row would work for my dataset because there would be 6 spaces. Is there anyway to combine the dates together as the delimiter?

["Inital" "Firstname" "lastname" "date/time1" "date/time2"] where the "date/time2" column could also include "None"

The code I tried using was,

```
dataset= pd.read_csv("newOutput6",encoding = "ISO-8859-1", delimiter="\t", names = ['Name','Date'], index=False)
tmpDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Initals','FName','LName','SignupTime','Waiver'])
tmpDF[['Initals','FName','LName','SignupTime','Waiver']] = dataset['Name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

sample csv:

```
 ,Name,Date
0,MA FName LName 10/25/2020 09:40 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
1,JB FName LName 10/26/2020 07:19 AM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
2,TB FName LName 10/25/2020 09:03 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
3,MB FName LName 10/25/2020 09:40 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
4,NC FName LName 10/25/2020 10:17 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
5,AC FName LName 10/25/2020 09:23 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
6,NF FName LName 10/26/2020 07:56 AM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
7,BG FName LName 10/25/2020 10:41 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
8,GH FName LName 10/26/2020 07:39 AM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
9,EH FName LName 10/25/2020 10:06 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
10,DM FName LName 10/25/2020 11:42 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
11,JM FName LName 10/25/2020 09:24 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
12,TP FName LName 10/26/2020 12:32 AM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
13,DS FName LName 10/25/2020 11:12 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
14,KS FName LName 10/25/2020 07:46 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
15,JW FName LName 10/25/2020 11:06 AM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "
16,DA FName LName 09/30/2020 07:44 AM 9/23/2020 6:06:38 PM,"October 26, 2020,9:00AM Until 9:50AM "
```

Index 16 is a row that doesnt follow the traditional format, and I suspect a regex is needed to determine that.

Comment: Use `.str.extract(r'^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)')` or something like that. Add more \s+ and \S+ where necessary (can't test on a mobile now)

Comment: What if Firstname or Lastname has spaces - are they escaped somehow?

Comment: I don't see any names that have spaces in them, do you mean like Tdel aney Last Name?

Comment: Okay, so the firstname and lastnames you refer to are always literally "FName" and "LName"? I assumed these would be people's names and people's names can have spaces in them. If the names could have spaces in them, we'd need a different way to split the string other than just using spaces.

Comment: So, that's a good way to state it, misspelling my own name, how would "Timothy De Laney" go into the file? One option would be `0,MA Timothy De Laney 10/25/2020 09:40 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "`. Another would be `0,MA Timothy "De Laney" 10/25/2020 09:40 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "` or perhaps `0,MA Timothy De\ Laney 10/25/2020 09:40 PM None,"October 26, 2020,8:00AM Until 8:50AM "`

Comment: @tdelaney The answer below showed me that there are no names that have a space in them, so that shouldn't be an issue until it happens :P. But there is a problem where the initials are sometimes missing, and therefore the regex command cant find a match.

Comment: Like "MA" and "JB"? Scrubbing data can be a whack-o-mole game!

Comment: Do you have any control over what wrote this file in the first place? It may be a better place to fix the format. A proper CSV output makes it easier to consume later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN the case there is no spaces in FirstName and LastName (else how you distinguish them):

```
pattern = ('^(?P<Initials>\w+)\s'
           + '(?P<FName>\w+)\s'
           + '(?P<LName>\w+)\s'
           + '(?P<SignupTime>\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+ \w+)\s'
           + '(?P<Waiver>.*)'
)

df['name'].str.extract(pattern)
```

Output:

```
  Initials      FName     LName           SignupTime                Waiver
0       DA  Firstname  Lastname  09/30/2020 07:44 AM  9/23/2020 6:06:38 PM
1       JW  Firstname  Lastname  10/25/2020 11:06 AM                  None
```

---

**Update**: For optional Initials, you can try this pattern:

```
pattern = ('^(?P<Initials>\w+\s)?'    # make initial optional
           + '(?P<FName>\w+)\s+'
           + '(?P<LName>\w+)\s+'
           + '(?P<SignupTime>\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+ \w+)\s'
           + '(?P<Waiver>.*)'
)
```

Note that, now if `Initials` exists, there will be a trailing space, which you can easily handle.

Comment: Thanks for the help Quang, I noticed that some of my data rows dont have initals. Is there anyway to prevent the whole line from being deleted if theres no initals?